# Is it overkill this use of map function to reduce code?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, dictionary

Is that the best way to reduce code duplication? Or is it overkill? How can I optimize it? Maybe I'm doing good :)

```
const Programs = () => {

    const programs = [{program: program_1, icon: program_icon_1, caption: "Graduation Degree"},
         {program: program_2, icon: program_icon_2, caption: "Masters Degree"},
         {program: program_3, icon: program_icon_3, caption: "Post Graduation"}];

  return (
    <div className="programs container">
        {
            programs.map(program => {
                return (
                    <div className="program">
                        <img src={program.program} alt="Program"/>
                        <div className="caption">
                            <img src={program.icon} alt="Program icon"/>
                            <p>{program.caption}</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                );
            })
        }
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: Which duplication are you talking of?

Comment: @Bergi I used map method and created an array of objects instead of creating 4 equal divs with different images and captions

Comment: Then yes, you're doing good, this is what you should do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Donald Knuth said that premature optimization is the root of all evil. So, first developers' goal is create a code that is easy to read and change.

`map` avoids duplication, and easier to read than `for` cycle. So, it is a good option.